# Voltage/current direction of AC on circuit diagram?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

Consider the following simple circuit consisting of an AC generator with voltage $V$ and a resistance $R$. As a result, current $I$ flows. Below the corresponding time-voltage diagram of the generator.

[image: simple circuit]

[image: time-voltage]

**Question**: aren't the directions (voltage and current) marked in the circuit correct only half of the time (i.e. during phase `1`)? Shouldn't they be reversed during phase `2`, as per the second image?

[image]

[image]

Obviously the answer is "no", otherwise the live wire would be neutral (and vice-versa) half of the time, so the question is "why not"? Why is the voltage/current direction always the same in an AC circuit in spite of the voltage on the generator changing 50 (or 60) times per second?

What I know (but don't quite get) is this:

- current flows in the direction of potential difference
- in an AC circuit the live wire is at a higher potential than the neutral (e.g. by 230V or 110 V, depending on the country)
- the values 230 V and 110 V are the "effective" voltages, meaning the peaks in the sinus-wave are higher in reality, and these quantities are some kind of average.

Assuming all of this is correct, the follow-up questions would be:

- "the live wire is at a higher potential than the neutral" -- does this mean, that in reality the live wire is at higher potential than neutral *half of the time*, and **at lower potential the other half of the time**? (But if yes, whey do we choose one of the two directions?)
- if the direction shown on the circuit diagram as **the** direction is a result of averaging, wouldn't the averages cancel out in reality, and hence the voltage/current have no direction at all?

Comment: The arrow labeled $I$ does not indictate the direction of the current  It defines the direction of the current that is counted as being *positive*. When the current is in the opposite direction the current is negative. For eaxmaple $I=-5A$  . Thus the arrow is the like the arrow on the $x$-axis of a graph that indicates which side of the origin in the positive side.

Comment: The drift speed of electrons in a circuit is very low.  Given 60 Hz A/C current, it is seen that the electrons in an A/C circuit wiggle, by a very small amount, back and forth around fixed positions, and there is no net flow of electrons in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> aren't the directions (voltage and current) marked in the circuit correct only half of the time (i.e. during phase 1)? Shouldn't they be reversed during phase 2, as per the second image?

Physically, yes, the current reversed direction.

In terms of the diagram, we usually indicate this by leaving the arrow pointing in the forward direction but taking the value "I" to be negative (I < 0).

> Obviously the answer is "no", otherwise the live wire would be neutral (and vice-versa) half of the time, so the question is "why not"?

Not true. If we ground the neutral wire (or just define it to be the reference potential), the the hot wire is always the hot wire and the neutral wire is always the neutral wire. In half the cycle the hot wire has a positive voltage and in half the cycle the hot wire has a negative voltage. In both half-cycles the hot wire is hot, but its polarity changes.

> What I know (but don't quite get) is this:
>
> ...
>
> - in an AC circuit the live wire is at a higher potential than the neutral

Not true. The hot (or live) wire can be at either higher or lower potential than the neutral wire.

> whey do we choose one of the two directions?

We choose a reference phase for the AC signal. Another signal that is 180 degrees out of phase with the reference will be positive when the reference is negative and negative when the reference is positive.

> if the direction shown on the circuit diagram as the direction is a result of averaging, wouldn't the averages cancel out in reality, and hence the voltage/current have no direction at all?

The direction is an arbitrarily chosen reference, not an average. We'd normally choose the reference direction for current to be the direction current flows when the hot wire has positive voltage.

But remember, with reactive loads (capacitors or inductors) the current will no longer be in phase with the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The reality of current in such an AC circuit is such that the current flows in one direction for half a cycle and then in the other direction for the other half of the sine wave cycle, this is the case just as the voltage also switches between polarities over the course of the cycle, i.e. +V for half and the -V for the other. Whether or not the wire is at a higher potential than the other depends on which portion of the cycle it is in.

It is true that the absolute average of say the voltage $V$, is zero over an entire cycle:
$$<V>={1\over T}\int_0^TV(t)\; dt=0,$$
however, this kind of quantity is of no importance in the application of AC signals. Rather, it is the *rms* value, or "root mean square" that matters in applications:
$$V_{rms}=\sqrt{{1\over T}\int_0^TV^2(t)\; dt}=\sqrt{{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}V^2_0\sin^2(2\pi ft)}\; dt.$$
The root mean square concept of average does not yield zeroes over the entire cycle; rated line voltages such as the usual $120V$ or $230V$ are just such *rms* quantities. Power, voltage, current, etc. are all root mean squares as opposed to simple averages. So in a simple schematic like the one you have drawn, instead of thinking about the reality of current switching its direction many times per second, one may think instead of an effective rms current that flows in one direction in analogy to a DC signal. This is why the power delivered by $120V$ DC is greater than that delivered by $120V_{rms}$ AC. In the AC circuit, the voltage is near the peak voltage for some portions of the cycle, but near zero for others. A DC circuit on the other hand experiences constant voltage.

Comment: The root mean square can be defined as:$$X_{rms}=\sqrt\langle X^2\rangle.$$